# Apache Ignite.NET persistence multiple nodes

Tags: .net, ignite

I've got a problem with Apache Ignite.NET configuration. What I'd like achieve is to start multiple nodes with persistent data regions configured.

My code:

```
var ignite = Ignition.Start(new IgniteConfiguration() { 

            DataStorageConfiguration = new DataStorageConfiguration()
            {
                DefaultDataRegionConfiguration = new DataRegionConfiguration()
                {
                    Name = "defaultRegion",
                    PersistenceEnabled = false
                },

                DataRegionConfigurations = new[]
                {
                    new DataRegionConfiguration
                    {
                        Name = "persistentRegion",
                        PersistenceEnabled = true
                    }
                }
            },
            CacheConfiguration = new[]
            {
                new CacheConfiguration
                {
                    Name = "persistentCache",
                    DataRegionName = "persistentRegion"
                }
            }
        });
```

When I start two nodes locally - one next to another, everything is okay and cout seems like:

```
Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=524c9527, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=8, offheap=26.0GB, heap=14.0GB]
```

Anyway, when i try to run exactly the same .exe (with same configuration) on another computer in local network, second node seems to be waiting for something, and first node repeats message:

```
Joining node doesn't have encryption data [node=8770f20c-...]
```

...and it never ends.

When I only remove persisted data region from configuration everything is okay. I am really new to the Apache Ignite and I'll grateful for help.

I am using Ignite version 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

`Joining node doesn't have encryption data` does not indicate a connectivity issue, it just tells you that [Ignite Data Encryption](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transparent-data-encryption) is not enabled - nothing to worry about in this case.

The actual problem seems to be the firewall on one of the machines (or both of them).
Please make sure the following ports are open:

- Discovery: `47500~47600`
- Communication: `47100~47200`

You may also want to open other things (from https://dzone.com/articles/a-simple-checklist-for-apache-ignite-beginners):

- Thin Client: `10800~10900`
- REST API: `8080`

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to work! It wasn't firewall - to be sure it's not a problem i disabled it.

I use nuget Apache.Ignite 2.7.6, when i made a configuration via C# code (as in first post), it just doesn't work.

So last thing i tried was moving the configuration to the xml file and... it works!
It has to be some kind of bug, because as Pavel said, 'Joining node doesn't have encryption data' isn't a problem (because it still occurs).

Comment: I would appreciate if you share the whole project, maybe there is some kind of a subtle bug, I'd like to have a look.